# How to restart a spring boot batch job by jobId

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have searched this questions somedays,some codes like this:

```
JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();

        jobOperator.stop(Long jobId);
```

but i can not find the jobId when the job is running.

Dou you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: how is your job declaration . put the code

Comment: JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                        .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .addString("topicId", topicId)
                        .addString("appId", appId)
                        .toJobParameters();
                JobExecution run = jobLauncher.run(etlJob, jobParameters)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problems.

```
public class StepExecutionListener implements org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        Long id = jobExecution.getId();
        JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
        String topicId = jobParameters.getString("topicId");
        String appId = jobParameters.getString("appId");
        JobHelper.jobIdMap.put(topicId + appId, id);
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

, we need add listener in step.